# Convert ddmmyyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: pandas, datetime, strftime

I have a df like this:

```
        SEMANAS      HIDROLOGICAS        METEOROLOGICAS
     0  02042020    36.00583090379008   31.284418529316522
     1  05032020    86.91690962099126   77.01136731748973
     2  12032020    87.31778425655976   77.24180581323434
     3  19032020    59.2201166180758    54.57343110404338
     4  26032020    32.39795918367347   29.049238743116323
```

I want to convert the column semanas to a format date like this: dd/mm/yyyy
I tried this code:

```
Semanas_Oper['SEMANAS']=pd.to_datetime(Semanas_Oper['SEMANAS'],dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

But i got this error:

ParserError: month must be in 1..12

How can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` is reading the month as `20`.  You can specify the format of the dates in the column: `pd.to_datetime(Semanas_Oper['SEMANAS'], format='%d%m%Y')`

Comment: instead of `dayfirst=True`, try to provied `pd.to_datetime` with the format; `format='%d%m%Y'`

Comment: Your life and sanity will be much improved if you change your software to use standard machine-readable date formats throughout. ISO 8601 is easy for humans to grok, too (though if you wanted to, you could adapt your code to display in a different format in human-facing interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Semanas_Oper['SEMANAS']=pd.to_datetime((Semanas_Oper['SEMANAS'].str[0:10]),format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

You need to have 'SEMANAS' in object type.